# Wordpress Walker Class Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I was learning how to used the new class called the Walker class but I to add a class to my dropdown ul tag.

> : Declaration of Walker_Nav_Primary::start_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /Users/brandonpowell/sites/valet/wordpress-development/web/app/themes/sage-8.5.0/lib/walker.php on line 10

```
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {
      function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ){ //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? 'fallback' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"fallback$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use class **Walker** instead of **Walker_Nav_menu**

> class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker {

Further more information here : [Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/)

Answer (score 3):

It means that the declaration of the **start_lvl** method in **Walker_Nav_Primary** should match the declaration of the method in [Walker_Nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/). It doesn't.

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
```

Replace to

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
```

Comment: thank you, mate for explaining to me and link me the website.

Comment: Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /Users/brandonpowell/sites/valet/wordpress-development/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php on line 14

Comment: i may have overlooked the error and forgot to see the order of the parameters